# How can I make a modal menu item?

Tags: menu, modal, styling

I would like to make a Menu item for a contact form.

I would like to either make a modal calling whatever contains the form (component/module/article) or opening it as a submenu, like in yootheme templates for modules (usually used for login)

Any ideas on how to do it easily?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily?
You can use a 3rd party extension.

One I am aware of, is the **[Modals by Nonumber](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modals)**.
Then you can insert the modals tags into your Menu Item title.

Comment: Have you tried? I did a quick try without much success, may be worth giving another try :)

Comment: did that work for you finally?

Comment: Haven't really tried yet, but I guess is the only easy answer ;)