# Create menu item that opens modal window

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item

I often use RokBox to open content in a modal window, and it works by adding `data-rokbox` to the `<a>` tag:

```
<a data-rokbox href="/images/my_image.jpg">This is a RokBox 2 Link</a>
```

But how can I create a menu item that opens a link in a modal window using the Joomla menu manager? In earlier versions of Joomla (not sure how far back this worked) it was possible by creating an external link, and *trick* Joomla into adding `data-rokbox` by adding your link like this:

[image: External URL with RokBox]

*(Note the additional quotation marks).*

This does not work anymore because the quotation marks are filtered out upon saving.

Are there any good ideas as to how I can make this work?

Comment: hello Johnpw, back in time I have suggested the modals plugin by Nonumber http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-can-i-make-a-modal-menu-item/115#115... Haven't tried recently, but I guess you could give your menu item a specific class and have modals plugin open this class in modal. Give it a try and let us know how it goes.

Comment: FFrewin's suggestion is the correct answer. I am using a similar setup to open a livechat box if it is during normal business hours for one of my client sites. Set a css class for the menu item, then add some jquery to fire the modal event you want to use (rokbox, fancybox, etc)

Answer (score 4):

back in time I have suggested the **[modals plugin by Nonumber](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modals#description)** in a same question question: 
**[How can I make a modal menu item?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/91/how-can-i-make-a-modal-menu-item).**

I Haven't tried recently, but I guess you could give your menu item a specific class and have modals plugin open this class in modal easily.

## From NoNumbers Modal Plugin Documentation:

### Open menu items in modals

> To make a menu item open in a modal popup, simply surround the menu
>   title in **{modal}** tags.
>
> So if your menu item title is Click here!, change it to **{modal}Click
>   here!{/modal}**.
>
> You can also pass extra variables in the tag as described earlier,
>   like: **{modal title=My Page}Click here!{/modal}** or **{modal
>   width=600|height=400}Click here!{/modal}**.
>
> If for some reason you don't want to use the **{modal}** tags (or it
>   doesn't work), you can also **give the menu item a custom classname**
>   (works with most menu modules) and **set Modals up to convert by that
>   classname**.

Answer (score 1):

@FFrewin This solution would work if you were custom coding a menu, but having a pre-built menu modules more than likely would not work since the menu is dynamically generated unless you modified the code. Your comment on the OP question about using a CSS class is indeed the correct method of firing a modal event form a menu item.